# Is this interaction endogenous or independent?

Tags: regression, independence, endogeneity

Imagine a multiple regression of the form

$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1 x_2 + u 
$

Now imagine that $x_1$ is endogenous (in that it is correlated with $u$) but $x_2$ has been assigned in a way that makes it not just linearly independent of $u$ (where the correlation between them is zero) but fully independent of $u$.

Is there interaction between $x_1$ and $x_2$ independent of, or correlated with $u$?

I'm inclined to go with the first option (endogenous) but I'm trying to reconcile this with the idea that if you have two random variables that are independent of one another ($x_2$ and $u$), any function of either random variable is still independent of the other.

Comment: $x_2$ and $u$ are independent of each other so any function of either is independent of each other, that's right. However, the interaction term is a function of both $x_2$ and $x_1$ of which the latter is not independent of $u$. Think of the interaction term as a new variable $z = x_1x_2$, then $corr(z,u)\neq 0$ because there in $z$ you have the endogenous part $x_1$.

Comment: What are you working on? It seems that you might need [instrumental variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variable) regression, also 2 stage least square (2SLS)

Comment: @Aksakal I have a paper with an endogenous treatment variable but I also have a variable which I feel has been randomly assigned to my sample. I wondering under what conditions would the coefficient on the interaction term (The difference in difference estimator) be unbiased. From my own constructed examples it seems that there is still correlation between the interaction and an omitted variable (OV).

Comment: @Aksakal However, assume the OV is distributed evenly within the endogenous variable, after conditioning on the randomly assigned one. In this case the OV can be included or excluded in the regression and the coefficient on the interaction will stay the same, despite the fact it's inclusion will alter the coefficient of the endogenous variable.